# What level should I print warning information to stderr?

Tags: c

While I do C programming, I'd like to print out some warnings for special case in order to make the program more robustly. However, I usually meet situation like:

```
float a(...) {
    float *p = NULL;
    if (p == NULL) fprintf(stderr, "err_lvl_2");
    ...;
}

float *b(...) {
    float *p;
    ...;
    p = Cal(...); 
    if (p == NULL) fprintf(stderr, "err_lvl_1");
    ...
    return p;
}
```

The warning information `err_lvl_1` and `err_lvl_2` are nearly the same? I think it's a little bit annoying. It will be worse if more high level nesting used. But I don't know at which level I should do this printing best.

Comment: There is a convention of printing out the "stack trace" that's grown up over the years. Not so trivial in C though.

Comment: `err_lvl_1` and `err_lvl_2` are not warning information level. I guess you need to implement your custom log level print function.

Comment: You might want to create a *complete, working program* in this style, and post it over at [codereview.se]. Be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there!

Comment: Note that the `err_lvl_2` message isn't going to stop your program from crashing when it tries to use the null pointer — though the context of testing immediately after assigning null to the pointer is moot (usually, you'd make the test to check a memory allocation, or something similar). This is somewhat tangential to your question. You should call a function other than `fprintf()` with more information (file, line, function, problem text or code) and you can arrange for that logging function to behave 'appropriately' — it might write to a log file, to standard error, to syslog, to /dev/null…

Answer (score 1):

Actually, these messages are not very informative. You want to be able to spot where something went wrong – and what. Therefor you don't need error levels at all. Imagine you see "err_lvl_1" on the console, but you used it at numerous different locations in your application...

You are better off giving more concrete information such as:

```
fprintf(stderr, "(%4u) %s: p == NULL\n", __LINE__, __func__);
```

You could place this into a macro such that you get uniform logging:

```
#define LOG(FORMAT, ...) \
    fprintf(stderr, "(%4u) %s: " FORMAT "\n", __LINE__, __func__, ## __VA_ARGS__);

LOG("value of x was %d", x);
```

(Be aware that `##` above is a GCC extension for the case there are no variadic arguments, which will then skip the comma – other compilers might require different solution...)

Sure, you can select more cryptic wording, trying to hide internals to the user, as long as you quickly get from what you need...

Levels, if available, typically are used to switch more verbose logging on (or off), either at compile time or when your programme runs (or both combined, such as below):

```
#define LEVEL_NONE  0
#define LEVEL_FATAL 1
#define LEVEL_ERROR 2
// WARNING, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE, ...

#if STATIC_LOG_LEVEL < LEVEL_ERROR
#define LOG_ERROR(FORMAT, ...)
#else
#define LOG_ERROR(FORMAT, ...)               \
    do                                       \
    {                                        \
        if(currentLevel >= LEVEL_ERROR)      \
            fprintf(stderr, "(%4u) %s: " FORMAT "\n", __LINE__, __func__, ## __VA_ARGS__) \
    }                                        \
    while(0)
#endif
```

Instead of printing to stderr, you might print to a file instead – et voilà, you just started some minimal logging system... You don't need to invent it up right from the start, though, there are enough of them out there already, such as [log4c](http://log4c.sourceforge.net/), for instance (don't ask me if its good, though – try it, if you don't like it, look for another... – or if you like, continue what I started above).

Why switching levels at all? Well, as long as everything runs fine, you might want to have less logging (for better performance, smaller log files, ...), but while developing/testing your application or in the case that soemthing went wrong later, you might want to have more verbose logging to track the error down...